# React Native refresh content when user hits back button - using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-hooks

I would like to refresh the data, when user is back from one page to another.
This is how my useEffect function looks like now:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then((response) => {
        const currentData = JSON.parse(response);
        setUser(currentData)
        fetch('URL',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user_id: currentData.id
                }),
            }
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                 setNotis(data.notifications);
                 setIsLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });
    });
}, []);
```

This function should run every time when user is on the page. Doesn't matter if it was onBackPressed or not.

Thanks

Comment: Add a dependency to your `useEffect` call that changes when you click the back button.  Not sure what that would be in React Native but if you're using something for routing it would be the piece of state that stores the route.

Comment: @Alex W it is possible to add isLoading as a dependency (without infinite loops)?

Comment: Not while it's inside of the useEffect call

Comment: Could you provide me a working example using the provided code sample pls?

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/usebackbutton-hook-to-handle-back-button-behavior-in-react-native-d7666226d644

Comment: Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: @Ian Vasco Yes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Using React-navigation**

We can directly refresh screen if you're using **react-navigation**

**Import @react-navigation/native**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
const isVisible = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("called when screen open and also on close"); 
    // this will call on both screen open and screen close.

   if (isVisible) {
      console.log("called when screen open or when back on screen "); 
   }

}, [isVisible]);

return (
    ......
)

}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that the screen is not being unmounted when navigating outside of it, so the hook won't fire since the component is already mounted. There are multiple options to solve this issue just as adding a listener when the screen gets focused/blurred or just watch for the changes for the `navigation` prop. For the last workaround, you could try something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then((response) => {
        const currentData = JSON.parse(response);
        setUser(currentData)
        fetch('URL',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user_id: currentData.id
                }),
            }
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                 setNotis(data.notifications);
                 setIsLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
            });
    });
}, [navigation]);
```

For watching onFocus event, you could import `NavigationEvents` from `react-navigation` and move the logic for the hook inside a function `refreshData`

```
import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation`
...

<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={refreshData}/>
```

Also, you should be setting the `isLoading` state to false whenever the Promise has settle, for instance you could use

```
.finally(() => {
  setIsLoading(false)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice of using finally function, but as I tried to work with "navigation" as the useEffect dependency, the function has not been called.. also I read about NavigationEvents (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) but it seems a bit weird

Comment: @csirkeautomata could you update your question and show the parent and the screen with its props?